# Dropped and replaced transaction still showing pending on UNIswap

Tags: pending-transactions, uniswap

I checked some of the answers given to a similar question but none of them helped to solve my situation, hence I am writing it down.

My transaction's status is now "Drop and Replaced" but it still shows pending on Uniswap interface and I can not use the coins I wanted to swap. The "approve" button while trying to swap is now unclickable for that coin.

My transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xab038a9d9d644c17414f270ca560f56faed95680e7d55244a63d26374491de13

I also tried to send O ETH to my address, didn't help.
If I put the nonce number, it gives a RPC error.

Totally stuck, appreciate help.
Thanks!

Comment: I know this is a silly question but... have you refreshed the page? Most UIs don't handle replaced transactions well.

Comment: Yes, I did refresh, I even did a full restart..

Comment: The sender of the transaction you shared has some interactions with Uniswap since you commented. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: Hi Franco, yes in fact, I think, you had a good point, I removed the cookies and cache of my browser and re-opened it a new time, it was okey. Thank you for your support!

Comment: I did that, but now any transaction that I'm trying to do via uniswap has extremely high gas fees (on the hundreds, if not thousands, of dollars)

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution why the transaction was still pending on the uniswap interface.

1. Click on your wallet address, in the upper right corner of the interface
2. Click on "clear all" located at your transactions.
3. Pending message should be gone now.

:-)